# Histogram in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a list of numbers.The list is like [0,0,1,0,1 .... ] .Presently it has binary digits only but later on it can have decimal digits as well. I want to plot a histogram of this sequence in the list.
When I use standard hist funcion of matplotlib library , I get only two bars.It counts all zeros and all ones and shows me the histogram with two bars. But I want to plot in a different way.
I want a no of bars = length of list
and 
Height of each bar = value in the list at ( position = bar# ).

Here is the code:

```
 def plot_histogram(self,li_input,):
     binseq = numpy.arange(len(li_input))
     tupl = matplotlib.pyplot.hist(li_input,bins=binseq)
     matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

li_input is the list discussed above.

I can do it in a nasty way like :

```
li_input_mod = []
   for x in range(len(li_input)):
   li_input_mod += [x]*li_input[x]
```

and then plot it but i want something better.

Comment: So basically you want a plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you describe is the way a histogram works; it shows you the distribution of values. It sounds to me like you want to create a [bar chart](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar):

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1]
plt.bar(range(len(x)), x, align='center')
```

which would produce:

[image: Bar chart]